# Response SOAP con caracteres especiales cuando este es muy largo. Node Js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, soap

Estoy consumiendo un servicio con Node Js, todo bien con la petición, esta trayendo los datos correctos, sin embargo, cuando la información de respuesta crece demasiado. Esta se daña y devuelve algo parecido a esto **\u001f�\u0008\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000��\u0007`\u001cI�%&/m�{\u007fJ�J��t�\u0008�`\u0013$ؐ@\u0010������\u001diG#)�*��eVe]f\u0016@�흼��{���{���;�N'���?\fd\u0001l��J�ɞ!���\u001f?~|\u001f?"\u001e�\u001e�\u0016ez��MQ-?�hw��Q�/�լX^|�Ѻ=�>���8z�T�����2/�U��+��** pero obviamente en grandes cantidades. Esto solo pasa cuando el response XML a devolver es bastante largo, del resto el XML regresa bien. Aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const url = "http://infows.dealernet.cl/wsinfodlnt.asmx";
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
    "soapAction": "...",
};
const xml = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:web="http://dealernet.cl/webservices/">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
<web:CentralDeInformacion>
<web:ctausr>user</web:ctausr>
<web:ctapwd>password</web:ctapwd>
<web:input>
<root>
<tipocns>O</tipocns>
<ruts>
<rut num="11111111" dv="1" serie="" />
</ruts>
<prods>
<prod cod="3401" gls="Comportamiento Civil" />
<prod cod="3407" gls="Contactabilidad" />
<prod cod="3403" gls="Comportamiento Penal" />
<prod cod="3402" gls="Comportamiento Laboral" />
</prods>
</root>
</web:input>
</web:CentralDeInformacion>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;
const { response } = await soapRequest({ url: url, headers: headers, xml: xml });
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que es un problema de codificación, no debería estar relacionado con la longitud de la respuesta

Comment: Probe con un rut marcando a traer todos los items (prods) y alli me lo trajo todo bien pero la informacion de esa persona no es muy grande, luego probe con ese y pues efectivamente se daña luego de que intento traer mas y mas información. Por ejemplo si juego con los prods a traer, eliminando 1 y luego otro va funcionando, luego cuando ya coloco uno que trae demasiado se vuelve a dañar

Comment: Puede ser que ese que trae más información tenga datos incorrectos.